# Background color and background image below element in Contact Form 7 - error tip

Tags: filters, css, plugin-contact-form-7

The idea was to make the not valid error tip that comes up when people fail to fill out a required field show up like a speech bubble. So the arrowhead image shows in the center and underneath the text and would point into the field that they missed.

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Dean_Wilson/D2KFX/1/)

**HTML:**

```
<span class="wpcf7-not-valid-tip">Please fill the required field.</span>
```

**CSS:**

```
.wpcf7-not-valid-tip {
        background: red;
        color: white;
        padding: 10px;
        width: 100px;
        background-position: 0 0; 
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-image: url('http://s24.postimg.org/qacevkf7l/green_error_arrow.png');  
}
```

As you can see I have a background color and the arrow image that needs to sit in the middle of the element and below it but, of course, if you position it using background-position, the image is hidden as it cannot overflow outside of the element itself. This would be easy if I could easily edit the HTML but I would prefer not to as I am using a plugin and want to be free to update the plugin in the future.

**QUESTION:**

Is there a pure CSS solution?

If not (and I suspect there isnt) what is the cleanest way to solve this issue? Would I use add_filter to alter the html to put a div around the tooltip that i could then add the bg image to? Something with css "content:", a js solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CSS arrows on `.wpcf7-not-valid-tip`: http://jsfiddle.net/D2KFX/2/

Comment: Great, can't see any downside with that. Nice one. Thanks.